# How to avoid extra spaces using web view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I my application I have a web view and scroll view. In my Galaxy S2 , it's works fine ,But in Xperia Z and some other device there are extra white space in right side. I don't know why it is showing like that . can anybody help me from in this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include your layout in the question (XML or code). A screenshot of the issue might be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you set your application for multi-screens support. I thinks it's your screen density error, mobiles has it's own dimension and desity for each pixel, so we have to do coding for them.